# Why android doesn't crash when there is some exceptions in button onclick?

Tags: android, exception, crash, onclick

I write a simple demo to test it.

------code--------

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String s = null;
            s.length();
        }
    });
}
```

}

---

The log shows nullPointerException, but app doesn't crash, just like it has been try-catched.

If I write [  String s = null;s.length()  ]  in onCreate directly,app crash.

Comment: Do you press the `Button` and it doesn't crash or it just doesn't crash when the `Activity` starts?

Comment: Yes, I have pressed the button and it doesn't crash.

Comment: I followed the same, and the app crashes!

Comment: clean your project then run.

Comment: I found the reason. I change the device to test and the app crash.

Comment: what do you mean to change the device to test?

Comment: @Hulk Sorry for answer late. When I run the project on htc one v(with a strange Android System),app doesn't crash.  And when I run the project on other android mobile phone, app crash.